# Parsing a list of dictionaries passed as a POST parameter

Tags: python, django, post, dictionary, iteration

I have a list of python dictionaries that look like this:

```
sandwiches = [
    {'bread':'wheat', 'topping':'tomatoes', 'meat':'bacon'},
    {'bread':'white', 'topping':'peanut butter', 'meat':'bacon'},
    {'bread':'sourdough', 'topping':'cheese', 'meat':'bacon'}
]
```

I want to pass this as a POST parameter to another Django app.  What does the client app need to do to iterate through the list?

I want to do something like:

```
for sandwich in request.POST['sandwiches']:
    print "%s on %s with %s is yummy!" % (sandwich['meat'], sandwich['bread'], sandwich['topping'])
```

But I don't seem to have a list of dicts when my data arrives at my client app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't say how you're POSTing to the app. My advice would be to serialize the dictionaries as JSON, then simply POST that.

```
import json, urllib, urllib2
data = json.dumps(sandwiches)
urllib2.urlopen(myurl, urllib.urlencode({'data': data}))
```

... and on the receiver:

```
data = request.POST['data']
sandwiches = json.loads(data)
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use the JSON libraries to serialize your array of dicts into a single string.  Send this string as a POST param, and parse the string back into the python datatypes in the Django app using the same library.

http://docs.python.org/library/json.html

Answer (score 0):

firstly make string of the list

```
import ast, requests

# request send code
dev_list = [{"1": 2}, {"2": 4}]

str_list = str(dev_list) # '[{"1": 2}, {"2": 4}]'

data = {"a" : "mynema",
        'str_list': str_list
       }

requests.post(url, data )

#request receive side
data = request.data

dev_list = data.get('str_list')

dev_list = ast.literal_eval(dev_list)

#dev_list --> [{"1": 2}, {"2": 4}]
```

Now you receive list of dictionary.